# Windows clients not seeing timestamps update on shared filesystem

Tags: windows, timestamp, fileserver

I work in an environment with a windows file server and lots of clients mounting that shared resource. On some clients, not all, it seems like they fail to see files being updated on the server. For instance, the timestamps won't change, or new files won't show up.

The clients are time synced to the file server, so it doesn't seem to be related to time/date synchronization.

Any ideas? I'm a unix/linux person so I'm a bit stumped. Googling hasn't revealed anything relevant so far.

One more detail that might be relevant. I have this filesystem mounted on a linux system too. The files are actually created/updated from the linux side. But then again, some of the clients seem fine.